# Is it possible to add an implicit operator in assembly A between types from assemblies G and M?

Tags: c#, .net, cil

Let's say there's a graphics API *G* which doesn't want to depend on any external math library and therefore defines all its vector parameters as bare structs ([like SharpDX does with its raw types](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX/tree/master/Source/SharpDX/Mathematics/Interop)).

Let there also be math library *M*.

A developer wants to provide *implicit operators* in assembly *A* to cast between the full type from math library *M* to the raw type from graphics API *G* ([another sample from SharpDX, but in this case the operators are defined in *M* instead of *A*](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX/blob/master/Source/SharpDX.Mathematics/Vector2.cs#L1530-L1538)). Note that both of the types have the exact same memory representation.

---

Afaik, there are no means in C# language to provide such operators. Closest that comes to mind are extension methods, but the user still needs to call an additional method to do the conversion.

Is it possible or are there any samples of such operators being added through IL rewrite? From my limited knowledge, I'd think it was possible but would appreciate additional feedback on the matter.

Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to do this by adding a layer of indirection. Have your intermediate assembly define a type to act as a host for your implicit operations.

Comment: I Second that @JonathonChase

Comment: @JonathonChase I'm pretty sure the C# cast operator resolution mechanism doesn't look for *chains* of conversion operators. I think someone like Eric Lippert even had an article on it. Implicit operators are tricky enough as is :)

Comment: I don't see how IL rewrite is going to help you. The compiler is going to complain and you won't get any IL to rewrite.

Comment: @Luaan Looks like I'm spec diving. So long as business operations occur in terms of the intermediary type and the casts only occur when actually delivering from one library to another it should be fine. Either way, additional indirection should solve the potential issue of chaining by wrapping the methods that accept or return either type with ones that accept the intermediary type and then perform the implicit cast.

Comment: @JonathonChase But that really isn't any different from performing an explicit cast, or just giving a static method to do the transformation. Implicit casts are quite a different beast.

Comment: @Luaan You're right, the problem you mention is absolutely present, and my solution is still subject to it. Even in that example, if I wanted to take a method that returned type X and pipe it to a method that accepted type Y, I would have to explicitly cast to Z in between. My solution intends to solve the spirit of the issue, and not the letter of it.

Comment: You might be looking at a lot of work for little (if any) benefit. Explicit conversions are good -- they show you were these operations happen. Implicit conversions make the very same operations invisible.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by rewriting IL of one of the two libraries, specifically, you would add implicit operator to the type (and in the process also add dependency on the other library).

But I think doing this is a bad idea: it means you need to use your own version of the library (i.e. you can't just use the version from NuGet) and every time you want to upgrade it, you'll need to run the IL rewriter again.

To me, this sounds like way too much work just so that you can write `Foo(bar)` instead of `Foo(bar.ToBaz())`.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my comment, here's an overly simplified example. The ask is essentially to be able to use the two types interchangeably. How do we accomplish this? By adding a third type. We then define all of the logic in our application in the terms of our new type, and wrap calls to the external libraries.

```
// External Assemblies A and B define the following types:

// Assembly A
public class X
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public static void SomeFunction(X item)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"X.{item.Name}");
    }
}

// Assembly B
public class Y
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public static void SomeFunction(Y item)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Y.{item.Name}");
    }
}

// We would create an implicit intermediary in intermediate assembly C

// Assembly C
public class Z
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public static implicit operator Z(X input) => new Z { Name = input.Name };
    public static implicit operator X(Z input) => new X { Name = input.Name };
    public static implicit operator Z(Y input) => new Z { Name = input.Name };
    public static implicit operator Y(Z input) => new Y { Name = input.Name };
}

public void PushToX(Z thing) => X.SomeFunction(thing);

public void PushToY(Z thing) => Y.SomeFunction(thing);

public void DoThing(Z thing)
{
    Console.WriteLine(thing.Name);
}

public void Main()
{
    var a = new X { Name = "A" };
    var b = new Y { Name = "B" };
    DoThing(a);
    DoThing(b);
    PushToX(a);
    PushToY(a);
    PushToX(b);
    PushToY(b);

    //A
    //B
    //X.A
    //Y.A
    //X.B
    //Y.B
}
```